# GLSL Shader compilation fails without error message

Tags: c, opengl-es-2.0

I got the following shader embedded in my code:

```
static const GLchar * frag_shader_rect =
    "precision mediump float;\n"
    "varying vec4 v_color;\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "   gl_FragColor = v_color;\n"
    "}\n";
```

When I try to compile this shader with

```
glShaderSource(shader, 1, &frag_shader_rect, NULL);
glCompileShader(shader);
```

I get an error message stating that the shader was not compiled, but the error message length is 0. I am completly stuck here.

Why does the shader not compile?

Comment: double brackets )) in glCompileShader?

Comment: sorry, I have a wrapper around that command that checks for errors which ive removed for this post, thats why. ill remove them

Comment: Random thought: Try adding a `#version` as the first line of `frag_shader_rect`?

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, it should be `#version 100` for OpenGL ES 2.0, as described in the [OpenGL ES Shading Language](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf) reference (on page 13, in section 3.4 Preprocessor)

Comment: Tried that and got the same result unfortunately :(

Comment: Without a [mcve] is hard to say anything

Comment: We would like to see more code...for example...the wrapper to check for errors.  Please also make sure you have updated graphics drivers.  Can you share that information as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is incomplete, so I find my self wondering if you created the shader correctly using glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER).

```
static const GLchar* frag_shader_rect =
    "precision mediump float;\n"
    "varying vec4 v_color;\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "   gl_FragColor = v_color;\n"
    "}\n";

GLuint shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(shader, 1, &frag_shader_rect, NULL);
glCompileShader(shader);
```